# add a new value to a lookup field

Tags: lookup-column, column

I have a custom list in SharePoint 2013.  This list contains text and lookup fields.  While I do not have an issue populating the text fields, the lookups are giving me trouble.

I found and tried this example from MSDN `'AssignedToId': {"results":[1]}` but I had no luck.  Is the 1 the ID of the value?

I have a drop down for the following items.

```
<select id='Division'>
    <option value=''>-- choose division --</option>
    <option value='1'>Selection1</option>
    <option value='2'>Selection2</option>
    <option value='3'>Selection3</option>
</select>
```

The values for each option are the list IDs in the source list below is the JavaScript I have been using.  If Division is in the JSON my add item fails.  If I remove Division completely the new item will be created populating all the other fields.  If someone has a better method I would appreciate it.

```
var divisionId = parseInt($("#Division").val());

var item = {
    "__metadata": { "type": itemtype },
    "Division": {"results":[divisionId]},
    .    
    .    
    .    
    .    
};

$.ajax({
    url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listName')/items",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: JSON.stringify(item),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert("Successful")
    },
    error: function (data) {
         alert("failed");
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance
Carlos

Comment: Is it a requirement to use JSON.. What are you working on, is it a Visual Web Part, a SharePoint page.. ?

Comment: it is client side.  The js is being referenced from SharePoint page

Comment: Just to be clear ---  You want to dynamically inject a new option into a select list at runtime via javascript that you include on the page?

Comment: I have a form, and when I save it,  the code should create a new item in a SharePoint Custom list.   I have a field that is a lookup but not required and if a try to include it, the POST does not work.  I missed to mention, I'm using REST API

Comment: This helped thanks, one thing I realized is the following.  I removed the Division from the REST call, and created a successful item in the list.  When I looked at the response for the fields there was no Division field but a DivisionId.  When I made this change in rest to "DivisionId": divisionId, even though the lookup field name is Division it worked.  I'm just wondering if this is the proper way, or is it more like a hack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you try:

```
var divisionId = parseInt($("#Division").val());

var item = {
    "__metadata": { "type": itemtype },
    "Division": divisionId,
    .    
    .    
    .    
    .    
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is incorrect.
As someone else has suggested - if you have a lookup field named 'xyz' you need to use 'xyzId' when saving value to it. It's a bit confusing but it works. I had a similar problem with lookup field 'QuoteID' and it works after I changed it to 'QuoteIDId'